# React js Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: reactjs

I'm not so much familiar with react code. I have tried to get the percentage and the calculated percentage to the state so that I could save the percentage value to database. I have following code:

```
getTotalPercentage(){

let totalCost = this.getTotalCost();
let total = this.getGrandTotal();

let per = parseFloat(total / totalCost * 100).toFixed(4);

if (isNaN(per)){
  return 0 + " %";
}

const prev = parseFloat(this.state.percentage);
const next = parseFloat(per);
if(prev !== next){
  console.log(this.props);
  this.setState({ percentage: next});
}

return next + " %";
```

}

And in return

```
<input
            onChange={this.changePercentage.bind(this)}
            name="percentage"
            type="text"
            value={this.getTotalPercentage()}
            className="input-sm"
            readOnly
          />
```

But I'm getting following error

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in `getTotalPercentage`. You are calling this function each time react does a render. But inside this function, you `setState`. React prevents you from doing this to avoid an infinite cycle of renders (where you setState then re-render then update state repeatedly).

To solve this, move all of the logic from `getTotalPercentage` into the `changePercentage` function.

Then change the value in the input component to be:

```
value={`${this.state.percentage}%`}
```